# nullReferenceException when using RichTextBox.SelectionFont

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, richtextbox

when the selection area is combined with 2 areas that has different fonts, it returns null. The code is below:

```
private Font myGetSelectionFont()
{
    Font t = this.workspace.SelectionFont;
    if (t == null)
        return defaultFont;
    else return t;
}
private void toolStripComboBox_size_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sizeString = ((ToolStripComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
    float curSize = float.Parse(sizeString);
    Font oldFont = myGetSelectionFont();
    Font newFont = this.getFont(oldFont.FontFamily.Name, curSize, oldFont.Style);
    this.setFontIcons(newFont);
    this.workspace.SelectionFont = newFont;
    this.workspace.Focus();
}
```

There is no problem to set a different font for the selected area, but i don't know the font size and other properties for the selected area. what should i do?

I think I can choose to set the font as the font before the selected area, or behind the selected area, but i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be to loop

```
private void toolStripComboBox_size_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float size = float.Parse(((ToolStripComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString());
    SetFontSize(richTextBox1, size);
}

private void SetFontSize(RichTextBox rtb, float size)
{
    int selectionStart = rtb.SelectionStart;
    int selectionLength = rtb.SelectionLength;
    int selectionEnd = selectionStart + selectionLength;
    for (int x = selectionStart; x < selectionEnd; ++x)
    {
        // Set temporary selection
        rtb.Select(x, 1);
        // Toggle font style of the selection   
        rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.SelectionFont.FontFamily, size, rtb.SelectionFont.Style);
    }
    // Restore the original selection
    rtb.Select(selectionStart, selectionLength);
}
```

Comment: thanks! but will the rtb.Select method change the richtextbox's appearance? --- i have tried, and it won't change the appearance.

Comment: rtb.SelectionFont will change it

Comment: but the problem only happens when there is a "break" of font family. Maybe i can use binary search to find the break point and then set the two part's fonts respectively? but there may be more than one breaks.

Comment: U might want to setup a new testproject and test the code i gave u. It should do the job :) without any exception.

Comment: yes, your answer was very perfect, but i was just confusing about the efficiency...